# easepick shall return daterange from - to dates into separate fields for arrival and departure

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Currently I am trying to use **easepick** as a booking calendar and I want the following:

Two input fields (ARRIVAL + DEPARTURE) + a BOOKING button.

- if either field is selected, the same daterangepicker should show up
- selected date range from - to should put the first date in the field ARRIVAL and the second date in the field DEPARTURE
- yearRange: "-0:+1", does not work. Website visitor can still click forward and beyond the 31.12.2024. Therefore, I had to hard code "maxDate: "31.12.2024"," but this is not my preferred option.

Currently both dates are inserted in the same field ARRIVAL.
On the website there seems to be a possibility, but I do not manage to get it working.
-> refer to https://easepick.com/configurator/

> Configurator > @easepick/range-plugin > elementEnd set on.

The BOOKING button shall send the arrival and departure dates separately in the format DD.MM.YYYY via method="GET" action="/buchen">.

```
<!-- QuickBookingForm --->
<form id="QBF" autocomplete="off" method="GET" action="/buchen">
<!-- Field Arrival --->
<input id="datepicker" placeholder=ANREISE/>
<!-- Field Departure --->
<input id="???" placeholder=ABREISE/>
<!-- Submit Button --->
<input type="hidden" name="lng" value="de">
<input type="submit" value="BUCHEN">
</form>

<!-- DateRangePicker --->
<script>
      const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
      ].map(d => {
          if (d instanceof Array) {
            const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'DD.MM.YYYY');
            const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'DD.MM.YYYY');

            return [start, end];
          }

          return new DateTime(d, 'DD.MM.YYYY');
      });
      const picker = new easepick.create({
        element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        css: [
          'https:///easepick/index.css',
          'https:///easepick/daterangepicker.css',
        ],
        zIndex: 10,
        plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
        lang: 'de-DE',
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        yearRange: "-0:+1",
        RangePlugin: {
          tooltipNumber(num) {
            return num - 1;
          },
          locale: {
            one: 'Nacht',
            other: 'Nächte',
          },
        },
        LockPlugin: {
          minDate: new Date(),
          minDays: 2,
          maxDate: "31.12.2024",
          inseparable: true,
          filter(date, picked) {
            if (picked.length === 1) {
              const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
              return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
            }

            return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
          },
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Bonus:

- summary text output above or below within the calendar would be nice (eg. "Stay from xx.xx.xxxx to xx.xx.xxxx (x Nights)"

Information:

- I do not wish to use an additional wordpress plugin.
- I would also use JQUERY if the datepicker can handle this as I want to.

Many thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the elementEnd to work, in your code, you need to add the option **elementEnd** under the **RangePlugin** options :

```
const picker = new easepick.create({
        element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        css: [
          'https:///easepick/index.css',
          'https:///easepick/daterangepicker.css',
        ],
        zIndex: 10,
        plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
        lang: 'de-DE',
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        yearRange: "-0:+1",
        RangePlugin: {
          elementEnd: document.getElementById('id-of-end-date-input'),
          tooltipNumber(num) {
            return num - 1;
          },
          locale: {
            one: 'Nacht',
            other: 'Nächte',
          },
        },
        LockPlugin: {
          minDate: new Date(),
          minDays: 2,
          maxDate: "31.12.2024",
          inseparable: true,
          filter(date, picked) {
            if (picked.length === 1) {
              const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
              return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
            }

            return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
          },
        }
      });
```